# View hierarchy constraint error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

### Summary

I have an iOS project that comes from the Xcode Master-Detail template. However, I am encountering a "view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint" error. The table cells in the master view have a tap gesture recognizer that segues to the detail view when a cell is pressed. On the second tap, the program crashes with the aforementioned error. Other issues related to this seem to happen when generating constraints from code, however I have been using the Interface Builder exclusively, so I haven't been able to find another case just like mine.

The detail view contains a UITableView and a UIToolbar. What's causing this? Thanks for your help.

### Xcode output

```
The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraints: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x16d79980 V:[_UILayoutGuide:0x16d791b0]-(44)-[UITableView:0x1729b000]>
When added to a view, the constraints items must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved before the view hierarchy is assembled. Break on -[UIView _viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
*** Assertion failure in -[UIView _layoutEngine_didAddLayoutConstraint:roundingAdjustment: mutallyExclusiveConstraints:]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Impossible to set up layout with view hierarchy unprepared for constraint.'
```

### Constraints on the tableview in the detail controller:

[image]

### Constraints on the toolbar in the detail controller:

[image]

Comment: I was getting this.  Check constraints for "all" size classes.  I had a top space constraint that I didn't create and that I didn't want. It was ghosted and I couldn't delete it.  I was able to check the "remove at build time" box for it and that resolved my crash

Comment: I found that by clicking the "installed" checkbox against the constraint that it then unghosted and I was able to delete it

Comment: I removed the ghosted constraint, and it fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting this. Upon checking constraints for "all" size classes, I had a top space constraint that I didn't create (or didn't remember crewing anyway) and that I didn't want. It was ghosted and I couldn't delete it.

Clicking the "install" checkbox to install this constraint for all size classes un-ghosted the constraint and then I was able to delete it, resolving the crash.